# Find function is not working

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I want to insert object of struct `one` as a unique key in map. So i have written `operator()` function but `find` is not working even element exist in map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
struct one
{
    char* name_;
    double accuracy_;
    one(char* name, double accuracy)
        {
                name_ = name;
                accuracy_  = accuracy;
        }
};
const float Precision  =  0.000001;
struct CompLess:public std::binary_function<const one, const one, bool>{
    bool operator()(const one p1, const one p2) const
    {
        if (strcmp(p1.name_, p2.name_)<0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(((p1.accuracy_) - (p2.accuracy_)) < Precision and
            fabs((p1.accuracy_) - (p2.accuracy_))> Precision)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

typedef map<const one,int,CompLess> Map;

int main( )
{
    one first("box",30.97);
    one first1("war",20.97);
    Map a;
    a.insert(pair<one,int>(first,1));
    a.insert(pair<one,int>(first1,11));
    if(a.find(first1) == a.end())
    {
        cout<<"Not found"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Found"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison class doesn't induce a strict ordering. You should change it to this:

```
bool operator()(const one p1, const one p2) const
{
    if (strcmp(p1.name_, p2.name_) == 0)
    {
        if (((p1.accuracy_) - (p2.accuracy_)) < Precision and
            fabs((p1.accuracy_) - (p2.accuracy_))> Precision)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In your version `first1` was less than `first` because `strcmp("war", "box") > 0` (first condition is `false`) and `20.97 < 30.97` (second condition is `true`), but in the same time `first` was less than `first1`, because `strcmp("box", "war") < 0` (first condition is `true`). You should compare the second dimension only if the first one is equal - that's the good rule of thumb for `less` comparisons.

Comment: @BartoszKP If there are three variables then how should I proceed in that case ?

Comment: @sawaan In the same manner, hierarchically. You check the `k`th variable only if all comparisons of all `i`th variables for `i < k` resulted in equality. In other words: if comparison for variable `k` gives inequality (doesn't matter if `x<y` or `x>y`) the result must be based only on this variable, without looking at variables `i` for `i > k`.